# get_post_meta does not work

Tags: plugins, custom-field

I am trying to get meta_key value but this code does not work .

```
  <?php $des=get_post_meta($wdm_auction->ID, 'Product_Year', true );
                   echo $des;
                    //echo $ua_active_terms = wp_get_post_terms($wdm_auction->ID, 'auction-status',true);
                   ?>
```

Comment: Please give error and put all code here

Comment: No error , I am not able to get meta key value through this , any help

Comment: var_dump this line $wdm_auction->ID.  ID get or not? and conform your key name same or not?

Answer (score -1):

Pulled with $post using global.

```
global $post;
$des = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['Product_Year'], true);
echo $des;
```